# Paperclip/docsplit "has_attached_file" not reconized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I want to convert a docx file to pdf. I find this gem : https://github.com/tienle/docsplit-paperclip-processor

But when i put the code in the example in my controller I have an error

`undefined method 'has_attached_file' for #<CvsController:0x83c3cb8>`

I have paperclip installed (I already use it in order to save an image in database and it appear in the list when I do `bundle list`)
I have docsplit installed and I have filemagic installed.

I put this code in my controller (with the path of my docx file) :

```
has_attached_file :file, :default_url => "#{Rails.root}/#{@cvmodif.nom}.docx",
                  :style => {
                     :pdf => {
                          :format => "pdf",
                          :processors => [:docsplit_pdf]
                      }
                  }
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: I've not used that gem but looking at the docs it looks like `has_attached_file` goes in the model, not the controller. https://github.com/tienle/docsplit-paperclip-processor/blob/b4707e217be34e3479b45689dc09a74971f90dba/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made ​​a mistake. Read the documentation carefully.
You can move your code from controller to model(!).